# Ajax UpdatePanel does not working with Ext.Net ViewPort. Please suggest what can be done for this issue?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

Update Panel does not working when i use and test ext.net viewport web control.
Interesting, Update Panel is working fine with other provided web control of Ext.net.
Please let me know how to fix this?
Sample code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ext:Viewport ID="Viewport2" runat="server" Layout="border">
            <Items>
                <ext:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Collapsible="True" Height="100" Region="North"
                    Split="True" Title="North">
                    <Content>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </Content>
                </ext:Panel>
                <ext:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Collapsible="true" Layout="Fit" Region="East"

                <ext:Panel ID="Panel10" runat="server" Collapsible="true" Height="100" Region="South"
                    Split="true" Title="South">
                    <Items>
                    </Items>
                </ext:Panel>

                <ext:Panel ID="Panel14" runat="server" Layout="Fit" Region="Center" Title="Center">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Border="false" Title="Center">
                            <Items>
                                <ext:Panel ID="Panel15" runat="server" Closable="true" Title="Tab 1">
                                    <Content>
                <asp:MultiView ID="mvMiddle1" runat="server">
                                <asp:View ID="vMiddleGrid_JK1" runat="server">
                    //Do something
                    </asp:View>
                                    <asp:View ID="vMiddleGrid_JK2" runat="server">
                    //Do something
                    </asp:View>
                </Content>
                                </ext:Panel>
                                <ext:Panel ID="Panel16" runat="server" Title="Tab 2">
                                   <Content>
                <asp:MultiView ID="mvMiddle2" runat="server">
                                <asp:View ID="vMiddleGrid2_new" runat="server">
                    //Do something
                    </asp:View>
                                    <asp:View ID="vMiddleGrid2_old" runat="server">
                    //Do something
                    </asp:View>
                </Content>
                                </ext:Panel>
                            </Items>
                        </ext:TabPanel>
                    </Items>
                </ext:Panel>
            </Items>
        </ext:Viewport>
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am using the ScriptManager & ResourceManager. If I remove viewport control and work around with div then things are running fine.
Here in the sample code, when i click on the asp button and based on the bll, mvMiddle1 will set to ActiveViewIndex 0 or 1. This is how it should behave instead it get reload or postback every time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to remove the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`. The `UpdatePanel` is not required, and definitely should not be used to wrap the whole Page.

Comment: In this case, how do we achieve partial rendering of page?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your requirements? Maybe post a code sample demonstrating your requirement.